# Android studio lightbulb

Tags: android-studio

Sometimes in android studio, a light bulb will show up on the left side of my editor with a suggestion on changes to be made to code.

What is this called and how do I disable it, or modify when it shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called Intentions.
You can disable them one by one or by group in File > Settings > Editor > Intentions.